# Let f be whole such that $z_0$, $z_1$ $\in\mathbb{C}$ $\mathbb{R}$-independant, with $f(z+z_0)=f(z)=f(z+z_1)$ $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I have to show that, if the title is true, then f is constant.

I can't find the way to approach this. I thought using the fact that, since f is whole, $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ for some $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$. Then $f(0)=a_0=f(z_0)=f(z_1)$. I wanted to show that $g(z) = f(z)-a_0$ trying to build a convergent sequence of zeros of $g(z)$ using the $z_0$ and $z_1$ so I could use the identity principle.

I tried it less, because I couldn't find a way to use it, but tried showing that using the $g$ defined above, $g^{(n)}(0)=0$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are right. I didn't find it. Thanks

Comment: Note that what you call “whole function” is usually called an “entire function”.

Comment: Thanks. The translation problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_0$ and $z_1$ are $\mathbb{R}$-independent, for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ you can write $z = (n + r_0) z_0 + (m + r_1) z_1$ for some $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r_1, r_2 \in [0,1)$. Then we have:
$$\begin{align*}
f(z) & = f((n + r_0) z_0 + (m + r_1) z_1) \\
& = f(r_0z_0 + r_1z_1)
\end{align*}
$$
Thus, we have that$f(\mathbb{C}) \subseteq f(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is the set of all linear combinations of $z_1$ and $z_2$ with coefficients in $[0,1]$. That is, $\Omega$ is a closed parallelogram. $\Omega$ is clearly compact, and thus the image $f(\Omega)$ is bounded. Then by the above inclusion, $f$ is a bounded entire function, and hence is constant by Liouville's theorem.